# Cannot load driver : impala-2.6.15.1017 for Weblogic12c

Tags: datasource, weblogic12c, impala

Based on the below url, we placed the `impala-2.6.15.1017` jar file under `domains/tn8_dt_shared_01_domain/lib/` folder and restarted the servers. While configuring the Impala datasource we are getting error `cannot load driver : impala`.

For this issue I raised the Oracle SR, to which oracle responded: *"Reviewed the attached admin server logs and I could see the impala drivers are loading properly during server startup. We recommend that the issue be referred to the vendor of the JDBC driver ( Cloudera.com ).)"*.

Does anybody have the official documentation for configuring Impala datasource from Weblogic 12213?

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/impala-jdbc-weblogic.rst

(In WebLogic 12.2.1 if you want to add the driver to a specific domain, you can simply place the driver JAR and .lic file into `DOMAIN_HOME\lib`; for example, `ORACLE_HOME\user_projects\domains\MY_DOMAIN\lib`. These files will be added to the server classpath at startup.)

Comment: How are you creating your datasource ? With the console or with WLST for instance ?

Comment: I am creating the datasource from Weblogic Admin console.

Comment: You can check  
-the driver jar file is in the $DOMAIN_HOME/lib folder  
-the class cdata.jdbc.apacheimpala.ApacheImpalaDriver is present in the jar file  
-you are using the correct driver class when creating the datasource : cdata.jdbc.apacheimpala.ApacheImpalaDriver

Comment: Yes I placed the jar in the $DOMAIL/lid folder and jar got reflected after restarted the server. This is the "cdata.jdbc.apacheimpala.ApacheImpalaDriver" Driver class name I provided, still I am getting error.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message including any stack trace written in the server log file when you try to configure the datasource ?